# Turn NSManagedObject into a partial fault where some fields are nil and some not

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Apple describes faults as `partially materialised futures` which is very similar to the term `partially materialised views` used in several databases. Word partial means for me that some field of this object are initialised (realised) and some not. But Apple describes faults as:

> A managed object fault is an instance of the appropriate class, but its persistent variables are not yet initialized.

Are there any way to partially realise a fault? E.g. I have object with 10 field and I want a partial object with only two fields realised while the whole object is still a fault (hence all other fields are still nil). I'm not talking about `propertiesToFetch` of `NSFetchRequest` here but about so called partial faults. 
Because currently when fault is fired all properties are realised. Here is a quote from the docs:

> If you access a property on the Department object — its name, for example — the fault fires and Core Data executes a fetch for you to retrieve all of the object's attributes

How can I customise fault realisation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that there is anyway to do this. When core data loads a managedObject it loads everything.  You can see in NSMangedObject's interface that it has a single property of `isFault` which is either true of false.

If you have a property that is very large (a blob of data for example) and don't want to load it unless it is needed, then I would suggest storing it as a separate entity with a relationship.  This way it will only be loaded (faulted) when you request the property.

Comment: this is not what the documentation suggests (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506851-propertiestofetch). `propertiestofetch` can be set with managedObjectResultType and thereby implement a partial faulting (whereby only some of the properties are populated) of the returned objects